# NSLayoutConstraints for portrait orientation in vc1 reported as broken when vc2 is presented in landscape

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, modalviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an app for iPhone which was designed for portrait orientation only. With one view controller as an exception - this one has to be always in landscape.

I present landscape `vc2` modally from portrait `vc1`. It works relatively fine so far. I did have to implement some trickery like custom `func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask` to force `vc2` into landscape. Pretty much based on this [link](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/).

When I present `vc2` which changes interface orientation I hit a symbolic breakpoint in `vc1` for non-satisfiable NSLayoutConstraints. I have checked why - and of course it is because constraints are written for portrait orientation and cannot be satisfied in landscape view frame. I have made a set of constraints for landscape according to adaptability for iOS apps but it seems that landscape constraints are not used when I get `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`.

My question is: how can I deal with this properly and why/when this happens?

Comment: These kind of issues are hard to debug without seeing what constraints are breaking.  I was going to say that it is breaking because even though you presented vc2, vc1 is still loaded, and moving to landscape breaks the constraints for vc1.  BUT you said you have provided a landscape layout for vc1 when in landscape.  Could you post some logs?

Comment: @JacobBoyd I think your first point is valid, vc1 is still loaded and moving to landscape breaks constraints for vc1. I think the question is why vc1 thinks it is in landscape and why if it thinks it is in landscape, it doesn't use landscape constraints (which are setup as constraints for compact height)